# Media query font-size not resizing

Tags: css, media-queries

I am having trouble with h1 font-size not changing with a media query. I have tested changing other styles, and it works. So, I'm baffled why font-size won't change.

```
HTML:
<h1 class="header-h1">POVERTY IS NOT DESTINY</h1>

CSS:
    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    h1.header-h1{
        font-size:250% !important;
        color: blue !important;
        font-weight:bold !important;
    }
}
```

The font will turn blue and will be bold, but the font-size won't change.... Help?

Comment: Did you set the initial font size h1? In order for font size % to work it needs a starting value,  ie. 15 px

Answer (score 0):

For font-size: ##% to work you need to set the parent  font size.  Since % is in a percentage of the parent font-size. If you set

```
h1{font-size:16px}
```

Then set

```
h1{font-size:50%}
```

It won't work because your overriding the original font-size.

However setting  the patent font size for example the body. It will then work.

```
body{font-size:16px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0np59ueh/